# How was your weekend?

Tags: expressions

> It was okay, not best.

Have formed this by translating from language x to English.

How to say that is a neat way?

Comment: You just need a ***the***:  “It was okay- not the best.’

Comment: @jim put that as an answer, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some ways that really capture the way people I know would say this:

- "It was okay. Not great, but okay."
- "It wasn't the best ever, but it was okay."
- "Not the best. I mean, it was okay."
- "Okay, I guess. I've had better."